# Parametrizar un metodo con dos entradas

Tags: java

Tengo un método llamado *createTuxedoResponse* el cuál va a recibir un objeto *model* que hereda de la clase *BaseRequestModel*, pero como segundo parámetro recibirá una clase (**.class**) misma que NO hereda de *BaseRequestModel*, ¿Cómo específico que la **T** de `Class<T>` se refiere a otro tipo de clase que no hereda de *BaseRequestModel*.

Nota: No funciona con `Class<?>` ya que después necesito hacer un casteo y si uso esto, no me deja castear.

```
 private <T extends BaseRequestModel> String createTuxedoResponse(T model, Class<T> responseClass) {
        String tuxedoResponse = null;
        try {
          tuxedoResponse = mapper.writeValueAsString(ciService.createTuxedoResponseModel(model, responseClass));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
          LOG.error(e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tuxedoResponse;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private <T extends BaseRequestModel, S> String createTuxedoResponse(T model, Class<S> responseClass) { ... }
```

Comment: La respuesta parece bien orientada, pero en general, se espera obtener una explicación de cual es el problema y cómo tu respuesta lo resuelve y no solo una línea de código, Por favor lee [answer]. Un saludo.